# How many Blur Filter or Deblur models/modules are available in OpenCV or other python libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a project where I have to **remove noise**, **filter blur**, and so many image preprocessing things to be applied in a real-time video to enhance the video quality. So at first, I broke down the video into frames then I wanted to use all the mechanisms.

So, my question is, which **deblur** approach should I apply to get my desired result, or is there any **python library** that will be better for my work?

Comment: It very much depends on what the issues with your source material is. i.e for white noise youd use a gaussian blur and for dead pixels a median filter. For motion blur a point spread function would work id guess

Comment: Maybe I have to apply all of them cause in the real-time video the possibility of these circumstances is high and it can be happen! @Eumel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could start with scikit-image's [Image Deconvolution](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/filters/plot_restoration.html) to "filter blur" and [median filtering](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.median) to remove pepper and salt noise.
Seeing some images could be useful to help you more.

Comment: Sure! If you want to suggest more, please go on! @endive1783

Comment: There are plenty examples in the docs for denoising : https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/filters/plot_denoise.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-filters-plot-denoise-py, have fun !